# How to distinguish between multiple clients in client/server app

Tags: java

i am creating a simple client/server app 
and was able to connect multiple clients to single server.
i referred to this link [client/server simple app demo](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html)

my problem is that now,i want to return some response from server to client 
based on its client/ip address.

eg. if 192.123.1.1 connects the response should be xml

if 192.123.1.2 connects the response should be json.

is it possible to do?? any help will be appreciated

here is my simple server code:

```
    public class ChatServer implements Runnable
        { 
           private ServerSocket     server = null;
           private Thread           thread = null;
           private ChatServerThread client = null;

     public ChatServer(int port)
      {  try

           {  System.out.println("Binding to port " + port + ", please wait  ...");
              server = new ServerSocket(port);  
              System.out.println("Server started: " + server);
              start();
            }
           catch(IOException ioe)
             {  System.out.println(ioe); }
          }
 public void run()
  {  while (thread != null)
       {  try
        {  System.out.println("Waiting for a client ..."); 
        addThread(server.accept());
        }
          catch(IOException ie)
          {  System.out.println("Acceptance Error: " + ie); }
          }
   }
    public void addThread(Socket socket)
   {   System.out.println("Client accepted: " + socket);
       client = new ChatServerThread(this, socket);
       try
      {  client.open();
        client.start();
      }
     catch(IOException ioe)
       {  System.out.println("Error opening thread: " + ioe); }
       }
     public void start()                  
     public void stop()                    
     public static void main(String args[])
```

Comment: Each socket is associated with a client. Extract the IP address from the socket to distinguish clients. Write the appropriate data to the socket associated with that client.

Comment: instead of ip how do i send data to client based on some token? for eg. if client sends "send_players" server should return player list, if client asks "send_substitutes " server should send another list. how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API call  `Socket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString()` to get the caller IP

```
 Socket clientSocket =server.accept();
 System.out.println(" client ip address =" +clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString());
```

-- once you obtained clientSocket, use below sample to write back

```
Socket clientSocket =server.accept();
        String returMessage ="Hello from Server ";
        if (clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString().equals("192.168.1.3")){ 
            returMessage=returMessage +" welcome browser"; 
        }
        else if(clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString().equals("192.168.1.4")){ 
            returMessage=returMessage +" welcome tablet"; 
        }

        OutputStream os = clientSocket .getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        bw.write(returMessage);
        System.out.println("Message sent to the client is "+returMessage);
        bw.flush();
```

-- To read from client

```
InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String data = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("Message received from client is "+data);
        if("send_players".equals(data)){ // reading data you would need to finetune
          //write playerlist
        }
```

Comment: ok thnx thats nicc...but if i want to return response based on some token i.e sent to the server by client how to do that?

Comment: instead of ip how do i send data to client based on some token? for eg. if client sends "send_players" server should return player list, if client asks "send_substitutes " server should send another list. how do i achieve this?

Comment: @Mohit, You allready have code here to read the client input, you can check what client says(`readLine` and based on that you can write (`write`)back.

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of ip check the client should ask for the type of data they want. I am not sure why you require a check on ip. But in future if you all more clients then you have to change the server code every time. Better to define the format in the client so that client can ask for data of specific type.

Not very sure about your requirement.

Comment: i agree with you,yes this will be problem for me in future! so instead of ip how do i send data to client based on some token? for eg. if client sends "send_players" server should return player list, if client asks "send_substitutes " server should send another list. how do i achieve this?

Comment: step 1 : Send proper message to client "send_players" or "send_substitutes". Step 2 : Read this message from server. Step 3: Send response.